# Matrix at each point of mesh

Tags: matlab, matrix

So I have a mesh grid

```
x = linspace(0,1,250);
y=x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y) ;
```

At each point, I want a 2x2 matrix (that I will find eigenvalues for).  But I cannot figure out the best way (short of looping through the whole 250x250 space).

Suppose my matrix for each X,Y was

```
M(1,1) = X
M(2,2) = Y
M(1,2) = sin(2*pi*X)
M(2,1) = X.*Y.^2;
```

What would be the best way to do this then get the eigenvalues for each X,Y?

Comment: This is a good question, I don't know of a way for MATLAB to do this natively, safe with explicit loops and reshaping, or by implementing the eigenvalue decomposition by hand. But [DIPimage](http://www.diplib.org/) can do this, it can represent an image where each pixel is a 2x2 matrix (or whatever other shape), and can compute eigenvalues for those pixels. If you're not afraid of compiling stuff yourself, use the beta for version 3, which is more efficient for this type of operation: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure by what you mean "best", fastest? here is a simple way to do that if I understood what you wanted (2 eigen-values per pixel):

Start with your definitions

```
x = linspace(0,1,250);
y=x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y) ;
S=sin(2*pi*X);
XY2=X.*Y.^2;
```

Then, we can use [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html):

```
for n=1:numel(X)
    M(:,n)=eig([X(n), S(n); XY2(n) , Y(n)]);
end
```

That's it, all the information is in M... 
This took ~3 seconds on my laptop. If you want faster implementation of the `eig` function for the case of 2x2 matrices you can use [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27680-multiple-eigen-values-for-2x2-and-3x3-matrices?focused=5154331&tab=function). If you want to go back from linear indexing to the 2D (i,j) index, you can use this to get for  pixel i,j the eigenvalues:

```
M(:, sub2ind(size(X),i,j))
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking best=fastest.  So my matrix elements are actually with a constant that I have to loop through (loop in loop) so I was hoping to not have to do loop-ception with this.

Comment: but you do it only once... so how big is your array?